# Comparing if values exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble as to why the statement below won't do as I expect. Below is just a snippet and i am trying to compare the two post variables to the database table...

```
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
       $user_databaseF = $_POST['firstname_'] ;
       $user_databaseS = $_POST['lastname_'];
       $table_check_query = "SELECT * FROM clients_table WHERE _first = '$user_databaseF' AND _surname = '$user_databaseS'";
       $result_of_table_query =  $mysqli->query($table_check_query);
    if(empty($result_of_table_query)) {
       echo " we are good to start" ;    // Im getting duplicates in table
```

I'm thinking its here `if(empty($result_of_table_query))`

Comment: weird... im assuming the results are always empty... dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty` function checks if variable is empty. But `mysqli::query` returns either a boolean true/false, or a `mysqli_result` object.

Your comparison `empty($result_of_table_query)` will be **true** only if `mysqli::query` return **false**. This will happen in case of query error. Empty result is not an error. I advise you to do this:

```
 $table_check_query = "SELECT count(*) as `count` FROM clients_table WHERE _first = '$user_databaseF' AND _surname = '$user_databaseS'";
 $db_result =  $mysqli->query($table_check_query);
 // as a result of a query you will have a mysqli_result object
 // to get values in a result use for example `fetch_array`
 $result = $db_result->fetch_array();
 // print_r $result to check what you have.
 // if all is cool there will be an array with key `count`
 // which will contain number of records. Check it:
 if ($result['count'] == 0) { /* you have no duplicates */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

`empty` returns `TRUE` for a value that is empty or evaluates as `FALSE`. An empty [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) is neither.

Instead, you can use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check how many results the query returns:

```
$result_of_table_query =  $mysqli->query($table_check_query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_of_table_query) == 0) {
    echo "we are good to start";
```